# Implicit conversion from float (number) to int loses precision

Tags: php

i used to use this formula before php 8.1

```
<?php
$number = 0;
echo log10(abs($number)) / 3 | 0;

echo PHP_EOL;

$number = 100;
echo log10(abs($number)) / 3 | 0;

echo PHP_EOL;
    
$number = 1100;
echo log10(abs($number)) / 3 | 0;

echo PHP_EOL;
    
$number = 10000000;
echo log10(abs($number)) / 3 | 0;
?>
```

and it worked fine but now i keep getting these errors from them after upgrading

```
Deprecated: Implicit conversion from float -INF to int loses precision

Deprecated: Implicit conversion from float 0.6666666666666666 to int loses precision

Deprecated: Implicit conversion from float 1.0137975617194084 to int loses precision

Deprecated: Implicit conversion from float 2.3333333333333335 to int loses precision
```

and i can not find or understand why it is happening now from the 8.1 docs

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're getting an implicit conversion to integer when you perform the bitwise OR operation via the `|` operator. It's an... odd... way to convert to integer. To avoid the warning, just explicitly convert instead.

Implicit:

```
echo log10(abs($number)) / 3 | 0;
```

Explicit via function:

```
echo intval(log10(abs($number)) / 3);
```

Or via cast:

```
echo (int) (log10(abs($number)) / 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Implicit variant
$number= "2";
$calc = 2 + $number;

// Cast variant
$number = "2";
$calc= 2 + (int) $number;

// Explicit variant
$number = "2";
$calc = 2 + intval($number);

// Everything is good variant ^^
$number = 2;
$calc = 2 + $number;
```

Comment: You need to add supporting information to your answer, because readers are not only interested in the answer itself, but also in the reason as of why is it the correct answer.

Comment: Sorry, i want to work on it.

Comment: Why is the last one 'Everything is good variant' ?

Comment: The last one, the value of $number is an explicit number, also without quotes.