# How do I fix Hex to RGB in PHP 8.0+?

Tags: php, colors, hex, rgb

I've had this code working for some time that i pulled from somewhere on the net, probably here. It converts Hex Code to RGB to make a gradient on a GD image.  I upgraded my server to PHP 8.1 from 7.4 and not it never produces and image and will just infinitely load with thousands or more "Depricated" Float errors like:

> Deprecated: Implicit conversion from float 45.99999999999999 to int loses precision

Original Hex2RGB code:

```
// Functions
function gradient($w=100, $h=100, $c=array('#FFFFFF','#FF0000','#00FF00','#0000FF'), $hex=true) {

$blockbg = imagecreatetruecolor($w,$h);

if($hex) {  // convert hex-values to rgb
  for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++) {
   $c[$i]=hex2rgb($c[$i]);
  }
}

$rgb=$c[0]; // start with top left color
for($x=0;$x<=$w;$x++) { // loop columns
  for($y=0;$y<=$h;$y++) { // loop rows
   // set pixel color
   $col=imagecolorallocate($blockbg,$rgb[0],$rgb[1],$rgb[2]);
   imagesetpixel($blockbg,$x-1,$y-1,$col);
   // calculate new color 
   for($i=0;$i<=2;$i++) {
    $rgb[$i]=
      $c[0][$i]*(($w-$x)*($h-$y)/($w*$h)) +
      $c[1][$i]*($x     *($h-$y)/($w*$h)) +
      $c[2][$i]*(($w-$x)*$y     /($w*$h)) +
      $c[3][$i]*($x     *$y     /($w*$h));
   }
  }
}
return $blockbg;
}

function hex2rgb($hex)
{
$rgb[0]=hexdec(substr($hex,1,2));
$rgb[1]=hexdec(substr($hex,3,2));
$rgb[2]=hexdec(substr($hex,5,2));
return($rgb);
}
////////////////////

//*----- Hex to RGB for Number and Font Color conversion -----*//
function hex2rgb2($hex2) {
    $hex2 = str_replace('#', '', $hex2);

     if(strlen($hex2) == 3) {
      $r = hexdec(substr($hex2,0,1).substr($hex2,0,1));
      $g = hexdec(substr($hex2,1,1).substr($hex2,1,1));
      $b = hexdec(substr($hex2,2,1).substr($hex2,2,1));
    } else {
      $r = hexdec(substr($hex2,0,2));
      $g = hexdec(substr($hex2,2,2));
      $b = hexdec(substr($hex2,4,2));
    }
    return array($r, $g, $b); // RETURN ARRAY INSTEAD OF STRING
}
```

Any help is appreciated. I had a whole image system and now it's completely broken.

I keep getting the error specially on this line. I already know float is deprecated, which is why I'm here and I can't seem to find the place to put a 'round' or 'intval'.

```
$col=imagecolorallocate($blockbg,$rgb[0],$rgb[1],$rgb[2]);
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? What keeps you from rounding the numbers? With a decent test suite, it should not be too hard to figure out the changes

Comment: they literally addressed this: https://php.watch/versions/8.1/deprecate-implicit-conversion-incompatible-float-string

Comment: nor is this the first time this has been asked:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71534654/implicit-conversion-from-float-number-to-int-loses-precision

Comment: @Mash. If you didn't have a solution, there was no need for the hostility. However I did try doing Intval and as that didn't work where i was putting it, it's why I'm here looking for a solution.

Comment: @Nico, I had tried putting Intval on the X, W, Y  an d RGB tags separately in different places, but I just don't know which place it needs to be at. I resolved a similar issue in my other code, but it didn't have this gradient code in it. The error specifically points to this line "$col=imagecolorallocate($blockbg,$rgb[0],$rgb[1],$rgb[2]);" so i figure its something there or before hand but i can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, from what I can see,

```
$col=imagecolorallocate($blockbg,$rgb[0],$rgb[1],$rgb[2]);
```

uses the following colour values to set the colour for the image: $rgb[0],$rgb[1],$rgb[2].
Now, these values have to be integers since as far as I know, colour rgb values cant be decimals. Which sorta raises the question how you are getting decimal colour values in the first place....but that is another can of worms. Anyway, what you need to do is use `$rgb[0] = floor($rgb[0]);`  to convert the decimal values to the closest integer value. Mind you, this may not give you the exact colour value you are looking for, but its a start. It will at least give you the closest colour for the image you are looking for. Do this before using the values in the colour allocate method and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried adding that right under `$rgb=$c[0]` since that's it's first declaration, but nothing changed. Tried again above the imageallocate, but yeah it actually still gives decimals and outputs the same error. I'm lost on it being decimals too for the same RGB reason.

Comment: Updated the post with the actual image of the error. Goes infinitely.

Comment: ok, thats odd. can you please give me what you get if you echo $rgb[0] and then echo floor($rgb[0])?

Comment: $rgb[0] with or without floor() outputs "46" exactly. no decimals. $rgb[1] outputs "55", and $rgb[2] outputs as "66".

Comment: ok....this might sound weird, but what does $blockbg outputs when echoed?

Comment: Nothing, just throws a fatal Error saying the object cannot be converted to a string

Comment: ok, does var_dump($blockbg); give anything?

Comment: It just outputs `object(GdImage)#28 (0) { }` giving nothing. I don't think it's supposed to output anything since its a GD Image and not a string value. This is a conundrum right?

Comment: So idk what happened, but all of a sudden it started working again like it should.... without any edits.....I honestly don't understand. This is without the floor or anything. Its rather confusing. Idk what i can learn from this experience exactly though because i don't knw the cause or resolve. Thank you for your time and input though Mash.

Comment: good to hear it. Most probably it could be a cache issue.....or maybe php just fixed something in their update? These things are called heisenbugs and unfortunately are not uncommon at all. computers are more unreliable than we care to admit :)