# How to resolve Implicit conversion errors in PHP8.2?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I use PHP 8.2(CodeIgniter 3).PHP Error was encountered.
It worked fine PHP 7.4

Error message

> Message: Implicit conversion from float 20.5 to int loses precision
> Filename: libraries/Hashids.php
> Line Number: 220

```
$half_length = (int)(strlen($alphabet) / 2);
while (strlen($ret) < $this->_min_hash_length) {

    $alphabet = $this->_consistent_shuffle($alphabet, $alphabet);
    $ret = substr($alphabet, $half_length) . $ret . substr($alphabet, 0, $half_length);

    $excess = strlen($ret) - $this->_min_hash_length;
    if ($excess > 0)
        $ret = substr($ret, $excess / 2, $this->_min_hash_length); // Line Number 220

    }
```

The code showing the error is below
`$ret = substr($ret, $excess / 2, $this->_min_hash_length);`

I found similar question as below.But I couldn't get it to work properly.
[Implicit conversion from float (number) to int loses precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71534654/implicit-conversion-from-float-number-to-int-loses-precision)

I tried modifying the code in my own way, but since I don't have any knowledge of PHP, I think it would be less confusing if I didn't write it, so I would like to refrain from writing it.

I am using Google Translate because I am not native English speaker.

Comment: Param 2 of  `substr()` requires an integer If you divide anything by 2 like `$excess / 2` it is likely to create a float `3/2=1.5` so cast that calc to int `(int)$excess / 2,`